# im trying to get a group of cells and there values repeat along a row. i have values entered from b5:bl5 and i need it to just keep repeating

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Google sheets-  entered values in B5:BL5 and i need it to repeat across row 5 all the way to og5. I need it to do it automatically.  I have tried a scrip that doesn't work cause i don't know what I'm doing.  I'm hoping there's a formula that can do this

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rOEU0rZsnO37OicRE5hBFvfMDMsFY1yBH61Q8RKmhXI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat the values in `B5:BL5` several times with something like this:

```
=let( 
  d, B5:BL5, 
  array_constrain(hstack(d, d, d, d, d, d, d), 1, columns(BM5:OG5)))
```

Put the formula in cell `BM5`.

Note that the values will be view-only because formula results cannot be directly edited. To make them editable, select the values and press **Control+C** to copy and **Control+*Shift*+V** to paste values only.